# Populate Complex ViewModel in Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Been trying to find an example of this but having no luck. Up until now, my use of KO has been limited to fairly basic tasks. Now I'm needing to load up a VM consisting of other models. Still trying to wrap my head around using the mapping plugin, but for some reason not getting it. The fiddle, has a working version but it is not dynamic. Ultimately, I want to load the json from an ajax call.

How do I load these up using mapping?

```
var ContestModel = function (cm) {
    number: ko.obervable(cm.number);
    time: ko.observable(cm.time);
}

var CombatantModel = function (c) {
    name: ko.observable(c.name);
    weapon: ko.observable(c.weapon);
    kills: new ContestModel(c.kills);
    takedowns: new ContestModel(c.takedowns);
    throws: new ContestModel(c.throws);
}

var DivisionModel = function (d) {
    name: ko.observable(d.name);
    combatants: ko.observableArray([new CombatantModel()]);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5vy52umm/2/

Any ideas to get me over the hump?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You were so close. Because `ko.mapping.fromJS` converts the array to an observableArray, you just assign its output directly to what you want to be the observableArray, rather than setting the array contents from it. (Alternatively, you could extract its array and set the contents from that.)

```
    self.divisions = ko.mapping.fromJS(divisions);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5vy52umm/3/

Ok, as pointed out in the comments, your constructor functions are

1. Not being called by mapping, because it doesn't do that
2. Not syntactically valid

I *assumed* your intent was simply to get your data loaded into your model, rather than to do that using specific functions. If you want to pull the pieces out of the JS data and pass them to your constructors (first making them into valid constructors), you could do that. You would not use `ko.mapping` for that, you'd just be passing ordinary JS objects to the constructors, which it appears are intended to do what `ko.mapping` does: convert JS objects to observables.

Comment: Wow really? Don't mind telling @HapiDjus what this will *really* do?
None of the object constructor functions are actually used. When you `console.log(viewModel.divisions()[0].combatants()[0])`, you will see that the object is a generic *Object* and not a `CombatantsModel`. Although it might not matter in this case, you could have mentioned it. So basically you can strip all code between line 1-20. (+ the properties are defined as in object literal & not constructor).

Comment: So fatally this answer **does not** answer the question `How do I load -->these [constructor functions]<-- up using mapping?`, rather it answers the question `How do I get this stuff to apparently work without knowing what I'm doing?` If OP defines functions on the prototype this approach will brilliantly fail.

Comment: They're not constructor functions. They're nonsense.

Comment: Chill... I stated my use of knockout til now was basic use. After getting the answer to work, I have since refined what I was doing. Sometimes the path to better code has some bumps. I'm one of those who learn by doing.

Comment: That was me being defensive about why I didn't use them. Not attacking you, really.

Comment: Roger that. First comment seemed a little harsh and out of scope